# Can't change Permission of AppCmd / Can't Run AppCmd from php

Tags: php, iis, permissions, appcmd

Im trying to create an little "plesk like" panel for iis for my personal use and fun.

But at this point I am stuck since php dont have the right to run the `appcmd.exe` file.

I was wondering how can I change the permission to let php run `appcmd.exe`

If I run `appcmd` in `cmd` as my `Nicolas` user I get the following
[image: not enough permission for running appcmd]
But when I run it as **administrator** it work fine.

Now I tried to just change the file permision and try to add the php user.

But for some reason I can't change permision on appCmd.exe
[image]

What can I do to be able to exec appcmd.exe with php?

Answer (score 0):

Run it as administrator. You can do it by mouse right click on the executable file. Find in the context menu item "Run as administrator" with yellow shield. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I am doing in cmd.  But I need to be able to exec the appcmd.exe in php And php dont have enough right.